# Soundcloud Javascript SDK: How does SC.get return tracks when no specific library/user/playlist is specified?

Tags: javascript, sdk, soundcloud

Using the Javascript SDK for Soundcloud, with example code as follows:

```
SC.get('/tracks', { genres: jazz},
```

You are supposedly returned an array of 50 tracks, how does the SDK determine which 50 tracks are returned? Is it most recently created? Is it random?

My testing leads me to believe that it is not random - for example if I add a loop to check through each track until it finds one with a playback_count higher than 20, I get the same track returned every time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

UPDATE: I think there's something weird specifically with the "genres" filter. It seems to take priority over every other filter. So even if you add a filter on created_at from 2013, if you add genres=electronic you will still get tracks from 2011.

Answer (score 2):

These are 50 most recent tracks uploaded to SoundCloud, with some caching applied.

Comment: Thank you gryzzly - but I'm filtering on a genre and consistently getting songs that were posted 2 years ago... I don't think it's possible that with a genre like "electronic" only 50 songs have been posted in the last 2 years.

Comment: Hey! Care to provide your query where you get old tracks? When I `curl` this one `http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?genre=electronic&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID` I get only ones created today